# How to enlarge pictures in the center screen while hovering mouse on them?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a list of items  with their pictures in a table. I want the pictures to enlarge at the center of the screen while hovering mouse on them. They are being enlarged but the pictures aren't shown at the center of the screen. How can I position them in the center of the screen?

Here is the snippet of the [code](http://codepen.io/petronav/pen/EKmxbE)

```
<style>
thead,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
img:hover {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(15);
  -webkit-transform: scale(15);
  -o-transform: scale(15);
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Tee-s</td>
    <td>range</td>
    <td>sizes</td>
    <td>view 1</td>
    <td>view 2</td>
    <td>view 3</td>
    <td>view 4</td>
    <td>view 5</td>
    <td>buy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IZOD Gray Round Neck</td>
    <td>450</td>
    <td>M-40</td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/z/7/IZOD-Gray-Round-Neck-SDL834378448-1-10f63.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/z/7/IZOD-Gray-Round-Neck-SDL834378448-2-1623f.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/z/7/IZOD-Gray-Round-Neck-SDL834378448-3-34272.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/z/7/IZOD-Gray-Round-Neck-SDL834378448-4-5c23e.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/z/7/IZOD-Gray-Round-Neck-SDL834378448-5-396b6.jpg">
    </td>

    <td><a href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/izod-gray-round-neck/671100311218">snap</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Donear NXG Green Half Sleeves Stripers Polo T-Shirt</td>
    <td>650</td>
    <td>M , L</td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n2.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Green-Half-Sleeves-SDL736800025-1-29669.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Green-Half-Sleeves-SDL736800025-2-83c4f.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Green-Half-Sleeves-SDL736800025-3-6c63f.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Green-Half-Sleeves-SDL736800025-4-9fcd4.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n2.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Green-Half-Sleeves-SDL736800025-5-6fa23.jpg">
    </td>
    <td><a href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/donear-nxg-green-half-sleeves/626643395322">snap</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Donear NXG Navy Half Sleeves Color Blocks Polo T-Shirt</td>
    <td>650</td>
    <td>M , L</td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n2.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Navy-Half-Sleeves-SDL736268703-1-4ac59.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Navy-Half-Sleeves-SDL736268703-2-feafc.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Navy-Half-Sleeves-SDL736268703-3-2622a.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Navy-Half-Sleeves-SDL736268703-4-9e956.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/c/4/Donear-NXG-Navy-Half-Sleeves-SDL736268703-5-2a00b.jpg">
    </td>
    <td><a href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/donear-nxg-navy-half-sleeves/625967695961">snap</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve the effect:

```
img:hover{
  vertical-align: center;
  -moz-transform:scale(15); 
  -webkit-transform:scale(15);
  -o-transform:scale(15);
  z-index:0;
  display : block;
  visibility : visible;
  left:50%;
  top:45%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

However I do recommend you use something like a pseudo element with the image as a background. With this implementation you will get poping issues because you are literally moving the element. Hope that helps.